# Basic Tip Calculator Android Java

Tags: android, button

I'm a beginning android programmer and I'm trying to make a tip calculator. This is the code I've written this far. I have two questions about this. The first is, why doensn't my calculate button work? And the seccond is, if this code is written clean? Or I'm I on the wrong track?

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Fooi extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    EditText etBill, etPers, etPerc;
    TextView tvTotal, tvTip, tvPerson;
    Button bCalc, bReset;

    double billamount = 0;
    double percentage = 0;
    double persons = 0;
    double tipamount = 0;
    double totaltopay = 0;
    double perperson = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fooi);

        Controls();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.bCalculate:
            if (billamount == 0 | percentage == 0 | persons == 0) {
                // toast text
            } else {
                Calculate();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.bReset:
            etBill.setText("");
            etPerc.setText("");
            etPers.setText("");
            break;
        }
    }

    private void Calculate() {
        billamount = Double.parseDouble(etBill.getText().toString());
        percentage = Double.parseDouble(etPerc.getText().toString());
        persons = Double.parseDouble(etPers.getText().toString());

        tipamount = (billamount * percentage) / 100;
        totaltopay = billamount + tipamount;
        perperson = totaltopay / persons;

        tvTip.setText(Double.toString(tipamount));
        tvTotal.setText(Double.toString(totaltopay));
        tvPerson.setText(Double.toString(perperson));
    }

    private void Controls() {
        bCalc = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bCalculate);
        bReset = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bReset);
        bCalc.setOnClickListener(this);
        bReset.setOnClickListener(this);

        tvTotal = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvTotal);
        tvTip = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvBill);
        tvPerson = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvPerPerson);

        etBill = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etBill);
        etPerc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPercentage);
        etPers = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPerson);
    }
}
```

Also about this line of code I'm not certain.  `if (billamount == 0 | percentage == 0 | persons == 0) {
                // toast text`
I want it to calculate only if the three EditTexts are filled. Can someone tell me if I'm wrong?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: your code is not bad if you correct your code according to the IncrediApp's answer, because it is a simple example. I advice you to follow java coding conventions. Method names start with lowercase letters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is written fine, except for your 2 thinggs:
1) Your if clause

```
if (billamount == 0 | percentage == 0 | persons == 0)
```

to "OR" between conditions, use double pipes and not a single pipe, so:

```
if (billamount == 0 || percentage == 0 || persons == 0)
```

2) You're not getting the values from the editTexts prior to calculating...
Move these lines (and add empty checks) to the beginning of the case of your onClick on the calculate button:

```
 billamount = Double.parseDouble(etBill.getText().toString());
percentage = Double.parseDouble(etPerc.getText().toString());
persons = Double.parseDouble(etPers.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Thank you! This solved almost all problems. A few to sort out, but I think I'll get there